# Configuring NFS server on OS X from Linux configuration

Tags: macos, nfs

I have a working configuration for my NFS server on a Ubuntu machine and you like to export this configuration on an OS X machine (High Sierra).

The Ubuntu NFS server has the following configuration:

```
/export 192.168.1.0/24(rw,fsid=0,insecure,no_subtree_check,async,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
/export/fs_drv 192.168.1.0/24(rw,fsid=1,insecure,no_subtree_check,async,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

Is there any way I can "translate" this configuration for an OS X server?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `man exports` should give you a good idea

Comment: I already went through man exports without finding what I needed